# Datatable export issue with utf characters

Tags: csv, pdf, datatables, export

I'm using datatable for my table rendering and other functionality.
Particular about export functionality in 'CSV' and 'PDF', I'm facing issue while having 'Hindi', 'Gujarati' or any UTF characters.
The same thing working perfectly with 'Excel' and 'Print' export.

Below is the code example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
   <tr>
                <td>મનીષ</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
                <td>الهندية</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: hi, I had the same problem this short guide made it work https://www.okler.net/forums/topic/data-table-convert-table-to-pdf/.  don't change the buttons array. just download and add the scripts files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing font in datatables pdfmaker extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548170/changing-font-in-datatables-pdfmaker-extension)